# Advagg only aggregating and compressing some files

Tags: 7, caching, css-js-aggregation

I'm using the Advagg module to reduce the number of http requests for CSS/JS files, but this only seems to work to a limited extent. In particular I'm concerned about why my theme stylesheets/js aren't included in the aggregation. I've played with all the settings including the bundler submodule to no avail.

Here is a list of the non-aggregated files:

```
/sites/all/modules/contrib/jquery_update/replace/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/jquery_update/replace/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_api/date.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_repeat_field/date_repeat_field.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/field_hidden/field_hidden.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/setting_entities/setting_entities_client_ui/css/custom.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/youtube/css/youtube.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/css/views.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/css/ckeditor.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/css/ctools.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/css/modal.css
/sites/all/modules/contrib/ajax_register/css/ajax-register.css
/sites/all/themes/my_theme/css/build/main.css
/sites/all/themes/my_theme/vendor/select2/select2.min.css
/sites/all/themes/my_theme/vendor/fullpage/jquery.fullpage.css
```

I know this isn't a lot to go on, and will provide further info if needed, but if anyone has some pointers to reducing the number of files it would be appreciated!

Comment: Go to the status report page ‘admin/reports/status’. are there any issues under AdvAgg that need to be addressed?

Comment: All looks good there "Advanced CSS/JS Aggregator should be working correctly."

Comment: Does aggregation work with a core theme? I’m guessing it’s a theme issue